# Submit on enter button keypress in cshtml

Tags: jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

Very new to MVC and trying to figure out how to attach a handler to a submit button so the user does not have to click the submit button.

I have the following JavaScript:

```
            //fix to add submit to the enter button
        function keypressHandler(e) {
            if (e.which == 13) {
                e.preventDefault(); //stops default action: submitting form
                $(this).blur();
                $('#btnLoginSubmit').focus().click();//give your submit an ID
            }
        }

        $('#myForm').keypress(keypressHandler);
```

and here is the markup for the _Layout.cshtml page:

```
<div ng-controller="LoginController">
<script type="text/ng-template" id="loginForm.html">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h3>Please log in</h3>
            </div>
            <form ng-submit="submit()">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <label>User name</label>
                    <input type="text" ng-model="user.userId" />
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" ng-model="user.password" />
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn primary-btn" value="Submit" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </script>
```

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to attach the script to the actual submit button.  I added an id to  but the JS is looking for the form name (I know it's not myForm), which doesn't appear to be defined anywhere.  Feel like this should be easy but I'm missing something.

Comment: replace <form ng-submit="submit()"> by <form id="myform" ng-submit="submit()">

Comment: I have to say, I'm a little perplexed why the enter key didn't already work when inside a form control - is that actually what you experienced?

Comment: I'm not totally sure what's happening but it seems like it's hitting the cancel button instead of the submit button.  So you enter your credentials, hit enter, and it closes the popup.  Then I have to refresh the page.  Not sure if the cancel button is somehow attaining focus.

Comment: So I switched the buttons, putting the submit button first, and now it works.  Kind of embarrassed I didn't think of that first.  New gig, lots of new technology.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to give the `form` an `id`:

```
<form id="myform" ng-submit="submit()">
```

but furthermore, you only need to submit the form itself:

```
function keypressHandler(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        e.preventDefault(); //stops default action
        $('#myform').submit();
    }
}
```

and then finally, you'd really need to hook it up to the document:

```
$(document).keypress(keypressHandler);
```